# find index of StackPanel in dynamically filled Listview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection, stackpanel

I am trying to find the index of the StackPanel in an ListView which is filled with an binding to `public ObservableCollection<Artikel> Artikels { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Artikel>();`.

```
<Window x:Class="KassaBlokboek.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KassaBlokboek"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
         WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        MinWidth="768"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Resources/LogoNew.jpg" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
        <TextBox PreviewTextInput="TextBox_OnPreviewTextInput" Name="TextBox" KeyDown="ProductScanned" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Width="768" Height="64" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,-25,0,5"></TextBox>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Click="ScrollUp" x:Name="HoofdButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Product naar boven</Button>
            <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Artikels}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="local:Artikel">
                        <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=HoofdButton, Path=ActualHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Naam}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prijs, StringFormat=€0.00}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Barcode}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Aantal}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Button Click="Verwijder"  Grid.Column="1">Verwijder</Button>
                            <Button Click="WijzigAantal" Grid.Column="2" Margin="25,0,0,0">Aantal</Button>
                            <Button Click="VerhoogAantal" Grid.Column="3" Margin="25,0,0,0">+</Button>
                            <Button Click="VerlaagAantal" Grid.Column="4" Margin="25,0,0,0">-</Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>

            <Button Click="ScrollDown" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0">Product naar beneden</Button>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Click="BetaalContant" Width="128">Contant</Button>
                <Button Width="128" Margin="25,0,0,0" Click="BetaalPinnen">Pinnen</Button>
                <Button Width="128" Margin="25,0,0,0" Click="Retour">Retour</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="totaalPrijs" Margin="10,9.8,0,0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="Totaalprijs: €0.00"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I need to find the index of the StackPanel, so i can edit the text in the "Aantal" TextBlock in the StackPanel.

Comment: Posting the xaml definition of your listview might increase the possibility of getting an answer. Also, if you must change something of your view from your code, it's better to have a binded property to just change it from your viewmodel.

Comment: It looks like "Aantal" should change on your Button (+ / - ) - Clicks. The buttons are outside of yout Itemtemplate. So the common way is to get the selected row index, which ist provided by the listview. That should be the correct index of the stackpanel.

Comment: @deafjeff no i can do that via the ObservableCollection, i need the index when i add a new artikel to the Collection and instead of creating an duplicate artikel in the list i want to raise the aantal on the existing artikel

Comment: You have a List of Items, and each item itself can grow in amount. This is to me a List of viewmodels, each keeping a list itself. So instead of dealing with a stackpanel of textboxes, make a datatemplate with an internal itemssource collection. That is a safe way and it follows your overall approach.